# node / mongoose: getting to request-context in mongoose middleware

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using mongoose (on node) and I'm trying to add some additional fields to a model on save by using Mongoose middleware.

I'm taking the often-used case of wanting to add a lastmodifiedsince-date. 
However, I also want to automatically add the name/profilelink of the user which has done the save.

```
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.lasteditby=req.user.name; //how to get to 'req'?
  this.lasteditdate = new Date();
  next()
})
```

I'm using passport - http://passportjs.org/ - which results in req.user being present, `req` of course being the http-request.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I've defined `pre` on an embedded schema, while I'm calling `save` on that parent of the embedded instance. The solution posted below (passing arg as the first param of save) works on the non-embedded case, but not on mine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass data to your `Model.save()` call which will then be passed to your middleware.

```
// in your route/controller
var item = new Item();
item.save(req, function() { /*a callback is required when passing args*/ });

// in your model
item.pre('save', function (next, req, callback) {
  console.log(req);
  next(callback);
});
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work on embedded schemas today (see https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/838). One work around was to attach the property to the parent and then access it within the embedded document:

```
a = new newModel;
a._saveArg = 'hack';

embedded.pre('save', function (next) {
  console.log(this.parent._saveArg);
  next();
})
```

If you really need this feature, I would recommend you re-open the issue that I linked to above.

Comment: I should have added that I'm defining `pre` on an embedded schema while I call save on the 'embedded parent'. Your solution works on normal docs, but not in the embedded case I'm describing. I've updated my question to reflect that, now I know it matters. Upping anyhow, since it answered my incomplete question

Comment: @Bill Is it possible to somehow pass objects/variables to `pre validate` middleware, not just `pre save` middleware? The use case is to pass in default values for fields based on the current user's preferences (the current user and preferences are attached to the `req` object in my express routes). I need to pass them before validate because those values (even if they are defaults) should be validated (there are some complex validations also: one field depends on another, etc).

Comment: Hi, I am able to access req in middlewar pre save, but the document is not successfully saved. It returns undefined `const savedItem = await item.save(req, function() {});`. There are no errors. And what should be inside the callback?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is really old question, but i am answering it as I spend half a day trying to figure this out. We can pass extra properties as options as following example -

```
findOneAndUpdate({ '_id': id }, model, { **upsert: true, new: true, customUserId: userId, ipAddress: ipaddress.clientIp** }, function (err, objPersonnel) {
```

And in pre update and save access as following -

```
schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (next) {
   // this.options.customUserId,
   // this.options.ipAddress
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: What about save method?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with 'request-context'. Step to do:

Install request-context

```
npm i request-context --save
```

In your app/server init file:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express();
//You awesome code ...
const contextService = require('request-context');
app.use(contextService.middleware('request'));
//Add the middleware 
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  contextService.set('request.req', req);
  next();
})
```

In you mongoose model:

```
const contextService = require('request-context');
//Your model define
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  req = contextService.get('request.req');
  // your awesome code
  next()
})
```

Comment: it works on save but context is lost on update :'(