# Setting created_by user with a Mongoose plugin using session

Tags: node.js, session, express, mongoose

Im using `Node.js` and I'm trying to make a `Mongoose` plugin which sets a created_by value to the current logged-in user-id. The user is stored in the session.

```
lastModifiedPlugin = (schema, options) ->
  schema.add 
    created_by: 
      type: ObjectId
      default: -> 
        session.user._id // Need access to session
    created_at:
      type: Date
      default: Date.now
```

I'm using `connect-mongo` for a MongoDB session storage.

```
express = require "express"
MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(express)
```

I know how to get the session from a request object or using the session store when you have a sessionID. The problem is: I dont have a request, nor session, nor sessionId in this case.

My question: How do you get the session in a Mongoose plugin? Or how to implement this functionality in a different -hopefully just as easy- way? It seems to me like a very common use-case.

Comment: Detected that my question was a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485302/node-mongoose-getting-to-request-context-in-mongoose-middleware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. As you've mentioned, you don't have `req` and all the attached session goodies available in your plug-in definition.

These values are available a bit later however: when you save your model.

So instead of setting a default, you want your model to automatically include the user_id when a model is being **saved**.

See whether [`.pre('save', ...)` is enough of a hint](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)  to figure this out.

---

I've tried it out myself using mongoose middleware. Even using magic tricks ([Intercepting and mutating method arguments](http://mongoosejs.com/)), I can't get a simple enough solution... I end up passing the `req` object to `.save()` (the middleware can then extract the session's user_id)... but this addition to `.save()` breaks the magic-ness of the middleware.

```
lastModifiedPlugin = (schema, options) ->
  schema.add 
    created_by: ObjectId
    created_at:
      type: Date
      default: Date.now
  schema.pre 'save', (next, req) -> # No callback required here.
    this.created_by = req?.session?.user_id?
    next()
```

when using this:

```
app.get '/', (req, res) ->
  # make an instance of whatever uses the plugin
  instance.save req, (err) -> # Callback required here
    # Callback to handle errors
```

---

I considered making an express middleware that removes the schema's middleware and adds a new schema middleware that knows the request object... but that solution is ridiculously hacky and is likely to break other mongoose plug-ins you're trying to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was already using the `.pre('save',...)` hook for the `updated_by` field which gave the same issues of course. I wasn't aware of the fact that you could pas extra parameters like you did with `req`. At least thats something. But like you said, "it breaks the magic".

Comment: Ive found the same answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485302/node-mongoose-getting-to-request-context-in-mongoose-middleware This shows that you need to use the `callback` in `next()`. If you'll add this to your answer I'll accept it as a correct anser.

Comment: Hey Michiel, you only need to pass in the callback if you're planning on making it parallel middleware, since our operation in this example is synchronous you don't need it. (See Middleware docs on http://mongoosejs.com/ main doc page, above "Intercepting and Mutating...")