# Mongoose - passing parameters to pre save - does not work in update save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to pass a parameter to pre save middleware on a mongoose model like:

```
subject.save({ user: 'foo', correlationId: 'j3nd75hf...' }, function (err, subject, count) {
    ...
});
```

It's being passed to two pre save middlewares

First:

```
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    // do stuff to model

    if (arguments.length > 1)
        next.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    else
        next();
});
```

Then:

```
schema.pre('save', function(next, metadata, callback) {
    // ...
    // create history doc with metadata
    // ...

    history.save(function(err, doc) {
        if(err) throw err;

        if (typeof metadata == 'object')
            next(callback);
        else
            next();
    });
});
```

It does not work on saving an existing model fetched from the db, but it does work on a newly created model.

It does work if I remove the parameter.

So if I call...

```
subject.save(function (err, subject, count) {
    ...
});
```

...it does work.

It looks like the callback never actually calls back. So maybe it's assuming the first parameter is a callback for save() updates.

For create, it does work with passing parameters

```
(new models.Subject(subjectInfo)).save({ user: user, correlation_id: correlationId }, function (err, subject, count) {
    if (err) throw err;

    ...
});
```

Any ideas on why it works for save() on create, but not save() on update?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

After searching and searching, this is what I recommend.

Do the work in a virtual field instead.

```
schema.virtual('modifiedBy').set(function (userId) {
  if (this.isNew()) {
    this.createdAt = this.updatedAt = new Date;
    this.createdBy = this.updatedBy = userId;
  } else {
    this.updatedAt = new Date;
    this.updatedBy = userId;
  }
});
```

If that doesn't help you, you might find this other answer helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10485979/1483977

Or this github issue:

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/499

Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743565/how-to-save-userid-in-mongoose-hook).

Comment: Don't know why the downvotes, seems like there's not really a clear solution to this problem and this is a helpful answer.

Comment: @yellowmelon Haters gotta hate :-)

Answer (score 0):

`model.save()` has an arity of 1 and that argument should be the callback function. I'm still not entirely sure how you've got everything setup as the style you've written your code in is a bit foreign. The model's save method can only take the callback like so:

```
Subject.findOne({ id: id }, function (err, subject) {
  subject.set('someKey', 'someVal');

  // You can only pass one param to the model's save method
  subject.save(function (err, doc, numAffected) {

  });
});
```

For an update in mongoose, we do:

```
Subject.update({ id: id}, function (err, numAffected) {
  // There is no doc to save because update() bypasses Subject.schema
});
```

This link shows where Model.save() is defined. You'll notice it only accepts one argument:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/3.8.x/lib/model.js#L167

Comment: That only applies to Model.update,findByIdAndUpdate,findOneAndUpdate,findOneAndRemove,findByIdAndRemove. I'm calling save(). It also does work, calling all middleware, when the passed parameter is removed

Comment: Hmmmm... I see what you are asking now. Could you share the "create" part of your code? Word of advice, in Mongoose parlance, the idea of saving, creating and updating all have very different meanings. When you say "update" most will think of MongoDB's native Update command. Thats the root of my confusion

Comment: Yepp, I was just mentally breaking it down as one of the CRUD operations. I assume that when a model/doc is not new (!isNew), that it does use an mongodb update() call, but with save() uses the hooks. Are maybe the hooks on save() connected differently for create vs update?

Comment: It's not the save function that is excepting the argument. It's the hooks middleware. That's why you call `next(callback)`, that's where the callback get's passed to the actual save function. Obviously it does allow passing some arguments at least most of the time

Comment: `(new models.Subject(subjectInfo)).save({ user: user, correlation_id: correlationId }, function (err, subject, count) {});` in this line, what is the `(new models.Subject(subjectInfo))` coming from? If its returning a model, then you can't pass two arguments to save like that.

Comment: And `pre` hooks have an arity of 3, one for the hook name, one to tell if the middleware should be run in parallel or in series, and then the callback. So if your pre hooks are accepting that argument, and its returning a truthy value, you are setting the hook to run in parallel. See here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: p.s. I've been running mongoose in production since v1... I'm not saying you're wrong, but I'm also not saying you're doing it right or by what the community deems standard.

Comment: I'm not the only one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485302/node-mongoose-getting-to-request-context-in-mongoose-middleware https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/499 It just appears not to be common or something you've ever encountered. Maybe there is a better way to get data to pre middleware, maybe through virtuals. But it's certainly something that's done is other object mappers

Comment: In the github issue you posted, look at AHeckman's (the project maintainer) last post on that thread. That is how you SHOULD be using the `model.save()` method. Sure, you can do what the other are proposing and discovered, but you will get inconsistent results. Its always best to follow the API and best practices of the tool, even if that means a rewrite on your end.

Comment: In any regard, if you need further answers to the inconsistent behaviors you are seeing, ask your question on that github issue post and AHeckman or others will be able to show you more.

Comment: This is too much discussion to be an answer.