# express js winston logging client ip address

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

In `app.js` i have configured winston to log mongoose queries.

```
mongoose.set('debug', function(collectionName, method, query, doc) {
      winston.log('info', { collection: collectionName, method: method, query: query, doc: doc }
  );
});
```

This is logging all queries perfectly to the file that i have defined. But i dont get the point

`How to log the client IP address with queries`

because **req.ip** in express can get me client ip address but this works only inside

`function(req, res, next) ()`

Is there alternate way to initialize and get the client ip address at `app.js`?

Comment: The client's ip address is a property of the `req` instances only, and is not retrievable from the `app` scope. This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485302/node-mongoose-getting-to-request-context-in-mongoose-middleware