# Is there a way to persist each current user id,so i can use it inside a mongoose hook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have created a JavaScript class that attaches certain hooks to any mongoose schema, and creates log data in the database about that certain schema (when a schema is created what was saved, when it is updated the before and after snapshot of data, and also which user made that change/save)

```
 let hooks = {
  preSave : false,
  preDeleteMany : false,
  postInsertMany : false,
  postDeleteMany : false
}
new GenericHook(UserSchema, 'User', hooks).init();

/**
 * @typedef User
 */
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

This is how certain hooks get attached to a schema, one of the methods from the class looks like this:

```
// POST: Triggers when Model.findOneAndDelete() method is called
    createPostFindAndDeleteHook(){
        let that = this;
        this.genericSchema.post('findOneAndDelete', async function(document){
            let currentUserId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
            let options = {
                model : that.schemaName,
                action : actions.DELETE,
                user : currentUserId ? currentUserId : null,
                before_data : document,
                after_data : null
            }

            await log.create(options);
        });
    }
```

The hooks are attached and they work perfectly fine, save the right data in before/after fields but the problem is that right now using the node-localstorage package, the last user to log in overrides userId item in local storage thus saving the wrong userId in the database.The item is set when a user logs in successfully.

```
localStorage.setItem('userId' , userData[0]._id);
```

Is there a way i can store the user id for each user and access it on the hook so i can save the right user creating/updating/deleting something from the database ?

Comment: Hey there! If what you are building is some sort of API server, the users should be able to send their ID along with their API requests. Or are you building something else?

Comment: Indeed it is an API server and the users are able to send their ID in the request, but the problem is that I do not have access to the request object in mongoose middleware.

Comment: Oooh, I see. As far as I know, there is no direct way of doing this, however, there are workarounds for it. You can check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485302/node-mongoose-getting-to-request-context-in-mongoose-middleware), a couple of solutions were suggested in the thread. I think the `reqeust-context` middleware might be a very good fit for your use case.